# Is there any sense in having both permissions ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: android, gps, android-permissions, android-geofence, google-geolocation

As I understand from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) when you have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION (GPS, cell towers, and Wi-Fi) then having ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION (cell towers, and Wi-Fi) in pointless as it's subset of ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

However when I look on permissions for popular geofencing apps (Life360, Family Locator) they have both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION defined.

**Do I miss something?**

EDIT: And I've found this in [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html):

> Requesting ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION implies a request for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.